# custom CKEditor color dialog

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have integrated ckeditor in my ruby on rails application. I have issue with color dialog. Each time when I have to set background color for any word I have to every time click on color dialog and then select a color by moving mouse to color position. This behaviour is required only if I have to change the background color. But what If I have to apply the same color to different words? This functionality is provided by "tinymce" editor.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted something similar, but basically, the CKEditor devs won't fix it to remember previously selected color, see https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/1749

They recommend you use [Copy Formatting](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/copyformatting.html) plugin.